# How to configure WP filesystem access in Linux (Ubuntu Server)?

Tags: linux, filesystem, ssh

Ubuntu Server, LAMP stack, freshly self-installed WordPress.

Apparently I can't use `direct` filesystem access method because files are owned by different owners (WP core unpacked by me and files WP creates by `www-data`).

I tried my credentials for `ftp` method, but either something goes wrong or there is simply no FTP server installed in stack.

Googled up suggestion to install `libssh2-php` and use `ssh` method. Filling my credentials (except keys, no idea what to put there) it worked for deleting plugins, but fails to install new ones with following error:

```
Downloading install package from http://downloads.wordpress.org/plugin/serverbuddy-by-pluginbuddy.0.1.6.zip…

Unpacking the package…

Could not copy file. /var/www/wp-content/upgrade/serverbuddy-by-pluginbuddy.tmp/
```

I am little lost which method to poke. Should I try to tweak and enforce `direct`? Or how to fix `ssh`? Or just install some ftp server?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, you install php-suexec, so that the php script runs as the file's owner. This allows the direct method to be used without requiring any permission changes.

Comment: I installed the `apache2-suexec` package but it didn't work out of the box and I got lost at googling settings. Anyway for my VM I solved issue with `ssh` by setting up password for `root` and using those credentials. Accepting this answer because it's more proper and how it should be done in production.

Comment: "Note: suexec methods should **NEVER be used on a single-site server** configuration, they are more secure only for the specific case of shared hosting."
From https://developer.wordpress.org/advanced-administration/server/file-permissions/.
While this resource didn't exist in 2010 (published 2023) I'm pretty sure that was true then as well.

Answer (score 0):

How about ...

```
apt-get install proftpd
```

I mean, suexec + root as the owner of the scripts ... could lead to undesired results.

I've documented some relevant settings on my blog: [proFTPd configuration](http://www.codefx.biz/2012/01/proftpd-making-apache-owner-uploaded-files-directories)